# How to know the difference between a zoom event originating from clicking the the zoom nav control vs a fitBounds zoom

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

Using mapbox-gl-js 0.47.0

I am listening to [mapbox zoom end event](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#mapboxzoomevent)

Is there a way to know if the the ^ zoom end event originated from clicking the maps zoom control, or from the [fitBounds](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#fitbounds) method being called?

I know there is a way to pass additional event data to the fitBounds method that I could key from to know.

But what if I did not control the implementation?

Hope this makes sense.